# Reconstruct / Build new array based on array items

Tags: python, arrays, serialization, multidimensional-array

I have an array composed of varied sub array like:

```
[{'x':'xvalue', 'y':'yvalue', 'group':'groupname'}...{'x':'xnvalue', 'y':'ynvalue', 'group':groupnname'}]
```

I want to create a new array or serialize the same array in the form of:

```
[{'groupa':['x':'xvalue', 'y':'yvalue'}}...{'groupn':{'x':'xnvalue', 'y':'ynvalue'}]
```

Apologies for putting the question in a very weird way, but did'nt had any better explanation of the problem.

My preferred scripting language here is python.

Sample data:

```
{"id":"jMGTsJXWiI","key":"s1","value":{'group' : "x", 't':'45', 'xs':'x5e8'}}
{"id":"545sJXWiI","key":"s3","value":{'group' : "x", 't':'415', 'xs':'xr58'}}
{"id":"xjMdT45","key":"s2","value":{'group' : "y", 't':'405', 'xs':'xs58'}}
```

Comment: Are these actual arrays or Python lists (with pseudo-syntax)?

Comment: Could you edit your question so that your example code uses correct Python syntax?

Comment: these are multi dimensional arrays...

Comment: Does the first group have a name `groupname` or `groupaname`?

Comment: the sub arrays are like, few will have 'groupa', few will have 'groupb'...'groupn'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is really a list of dictionaries, this would work:

```
>>> groups
[{'y': 'yvalue', 'x': 'xvalue', 'group': 'groupname'}, {'y': 'ynvalue', 'x': 'xnvalue', 'group': 'groupnname'}]
>>> final_groups = {grp.pop('group'):grp for grp in groups}
>>> final_groups
{'groupname': {'y': 'yvalue', 'x': 'xvalue'}, 'groupnname': {'y': 'ynvalue', 'x': 'xnvalue'}}
```

This assumes 2.7+ because of dictionary comprehension.  If 2.6-, then

```
>>> final_groups = dict((grp.pop('group'),grp) for grp in groups)
```

**EDIT**

To answer the question in your comment.

No, there is no `import group`.  Here is the complete script:

```
>>> groups = [{'x':'xvalue', 'y':'yvalue', 'group':'groupname'},{'x':'xnvalue', 'y':'ynvalue', 'group':'groupnname'}]
>>> final_groups = dict((grp.pop('group'),grp) for grp in groups)
>>> final_groups
{'groupname': {'y': 'yvalue', 'x': 'xvalue'}, 'groupnname': {'y': 'ynvalue', 'x': 'xnvalue'}}
```

The `{...}` is 2.7+ specific.  It is called a dictioary comprehension and if your python version is less that 2.7 then you can't do it like this, and instead can do it like I have listed above.

**EDIT 2**

How about something like:

```
final_groups = dict(
    [
        ('%s.%s' % (item['value'].pop('group'), item['key']), item['value']) for item in groups
    ]
)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'y.s2': {'xs': 'xs58', 't': '405'}, 'x.s3': {'xs': 'xr58', 't': '415'}, 'x.s1': {'xs': 'x5e8', 't': '45'}}
```

Comment: final_groups = {...} looks like something is wrong with the syntax. Also, with the first line, do you intend to 'import group'?

Comment: this seems to be working, but what if the array is in the format like [{'value':{'group':'xx'...}] or may be in even more complex format [{'value':{'something':{'group':xx'}}]

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem in a generic way?  Are there more possibilities for nesting?  You need to be clear about what input you expect.

Comment: Actually, its all the response from couchdb server. And yes, nesting should be fine. Also, I realized that this way grouping is very well done, but only for 1 sub array each group. What if there are 5 arrays which have different values, but same group names?

Comment: You need to give sample data.

Comment: added a small sample to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
>>> lis=[{'x':'xvalue', 'y':'yvalue', 'group':'groupname'},{'x':'xnvalue', 'y':'ynvalue', 'group':'groupnname'}]

>>> [{x['group']:{y:x[y] for y in x if y !='group'} for x in lis}]

[{'groupname': {'y': 'yvalue', 'x': 'xvalue'}, 'groupnname': {'y': 'ynvalue', 'x': 'xnvalue'}}]
```

using for loop:

```
lis=[{'x':'xvalue', 'y':'yvalue', 'group':'groupname'},{'x':'xnvalue', 'y':'ynvalue', 'group':'groupnname'}]
lis1=[{} for _ in range(len(lis))] # lis1= [{},{}]

for i,x in enumerate(lis):
    lis1[i][x['group']]={}      #creates lis1[{'groupname':{}}]
    for y in x:
        if y!='group':
            lis1[i][x['group']][y]=x[y] #add values to lis1[{'groupname':{}}]

print(lis1)
```

Comment: something with the syntax? I'm afraid, the second code line was too complex for me to understand

Comment: @yuvrajm added a lesser complex solution.